# Compress Video Stream using Node Js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I have video stored on AWS s3 bucket I don't want to store complete video on my node js server. I want to compress video and store it on another bucket. Is there any method so that I can compress the video stream without storing it on my node js server?

Comment: Sure, call ffmpeg to compress the video.

Comment: but I only get the commands if file stored on the local file system.how to process a stream of video without storing on the file system

Comment: use ffmpeg/ffpmegfluent, pipe it in from one S3 stream and pipe it out to another S3 stream.

If you're just dealing with a streaming format, that should work.  If you're converting to MP4, you have to store the entire thing on your server until it finishes then transfer the entire thing.

Could you elaborate a bit on your formats/process?